# What strategy should I use in my CNN to go from a 3D volume to a 2D plane?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

What strategy should I use in my CNN to go from a 3D volume to a 2D plane as the output layer. Can I even have a 2D layer as output?

I am trying to develop a network which input is a 320x320x3 image and output should be 68x2.

I know one way to do it would be to start from 320x320x3 and after a few layer I could flatten my 3D layers and then shorten it down to a 1D array of 136. But I am trying to understand if I could somehow go down to a desired 2d dimension at the final layer.

Thanks,
Shubham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I might have misread your question initially. If your intention is to have 136 output nodes that can be arranged in a 68x2 matrix (*and not to have a 68x68x2 image in the output, as I though at first*), then you can use a `Reshape` layer after your final dense layer with 136 units:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Reshape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, input_shape=(320, 320, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(136))
model.add(Reshape((68, 2)))

model.summary()
```

This will give you the following model, with the desired shape in the output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 318, 318, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 3235968)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 136)               440091784 
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 68, 2)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 440,092,680
Trainable params: 440,092,680
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Make sure to provide your training labels in the same shape when fitting the model.

---

*(original answer, might still be relevant)*

Yes, this is commonly done in semantic segmentation models, where the inputs are images and the outputs are tensors of the same height and width of the images, and with the number of channels equal to the number of classes in the output. If you want to do this in TensorFlow or Keras, you can look up [existing implementations](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet), for instance of U-Net architectures.

A core feature of these models is that these networks are fully convolutional: they only consist of convolutional layers. Typically, the feaure maps in these models go from 'wide and shallow' (big feature maps in the spatial dimensions with few channels) at first, to 'small and deep' (small spatial dimensions, high-dimensional channel dimension) and back to the desired output dimension. Hence the U-shape:

[image]

There are a lot of ways to go from 320x320x3 to 68x2 with a fully convolutional network, but the input and output of your model would basically look like this:

```
import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(320,320,3)))
# Include more convolutional layers, pooling layers, upsampling layers etc
...
# At the end of the model, add your final Conv2dD layer with 2 filters
# and the required activation function
model.add(Conv2D(2, 3, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Thanks @sdcbr! This is what I initially thought of bit thanks for clarifying.